# Compare activity from getCallingActivity to another

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I would like to compare the calling activity to others to know which one called the current activity. I tried:

```
getCallingActivity().getClassName().toString().equals(MainActivity.class.toString())
```

It doesn't work, except by passing a value in the calling Intent, how can we compare classes using `getCallingActivity()` or `getCallingPackage()`?

Comment: Hey @JerecTheSith how you solve this problem ?

Comment: Hey @HarinKaklotar you might want to check this out, I don't remember how I did it back in 2013 : http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=android.app.Activity&method=getCallingActivity

Comment: thanks @JerecTheSith

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can compare the calling activity in the following manner if the activity is started for result from another activity.

```
  if (getCallingActivity().getClassName().equals(MainActivity.class.getName())) {

            /* here the main activity is calling activity*/

     }else{

             /*other activity is calling activity*/
  }
```

Comment: hey i try this logic but it give me exaption like this: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.ComponentName.getClassName()' on a null object reference

Comment: did u started activity for result?? if not then `getCallingActivity()` will return null which will cause null pointer

Comment: if (getCallingActivity().getClassName().equals(PlayerActivity.class.getCanonicalName()))
                        code = 100;
                    else {
                        code = isPlaylist.equals("True") ? 100 : 200;
                    }

                    setResult(code, in);

Comment: use `getName()` instead of `getCanonicalName()`
see the differences here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202997/what-is-the-difference-between-canonical-name-simple-name-and-class-name-in-jav

Comment: try to log if `getCallingActivity` is not returning null

Comment: it also give null :(

Comment: then the activity is not started for result. start it with `startActivityForResult` then everything will be fine