# Deleting all Entities of a certain type

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpql

I am trying to delete all entities of a certain type from the datastore within my GAE application. I have the following line:

```
em.createQuery("DELETE m FROM "+UpdateMessage.class.getSimpleName()+" m").executeUpdate();
```

I am seeing the following exception:

```
 Unable to update most recent message in datatstore: Candidate class could not be found: DELETE
```

I'm assuming that I am not doing the aliasing right, as it is mistaking the DELETE for an actual class. I tried just doing `DELETE FROM MyClassType` without the alias, but that didn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove all entities you won't need a variable as explained here [1].

Also, you are using the method getSimpleName(), I know little about JPA but all of the code snippets I've seen use the getName() method instead. See differences here [2]. Therefore, the query would be:

```
em.createQuery("DELETE FROM " + UpdateMessage.class.getName()).executeUpdate();
```

[1] http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/delete

[2] [What is the difference between canonical name, simple name and class name in Java Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202997/what-is-the-difference-between-canonical-name-simple-name-and-class-name-in-jav)