# How to print a specific object type from an abstract class arraylist in java

Tags: java, arraylist, netbeans, polymorphism

the class below is my main class. My arraylist is the type of "Employee" and that arraylist contains many elements which are of multiple objects (polymorphism). So I want to know that when the user enters a class name, I should print out the employees of that specific class from the arraylist. For example, when the user types in "Surgeon", the program should be able to print out all the Surgeon employee's from the arraylist. Please help, thanks in advance.

```
 import java.util.*;


public class HospitalDatabase {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String q;
        String w;
        ArrayList<Employee> e = new ArrayList<Employee>(); 
        Employee s = new Surgeon("Christian Barnard", 2113211, "Cardiac", "Cardiology",
                2000, "Yale University");
        Employee i = new ITSupport("Mickey Mouse", 11280, Department.IT, 26, "Mac OS");
        Employee n = new Nurse("Florence Nightingale", 54678, "Urgent Care", 
                "Emergency", false, HospitalWing.North);
        Employee p = new PatientAccountsManager("Donald Duck", 32465, Department.PatientSupport, 
                99, true); 
        Employee s1 = new Surgeon("Sanjay Gupta", 42171, "Neurosurgery", 
                "Neurology", 500, "Duke University"); 
        Employee n1 = new Nurse("Mary Breckinridge", 56536, "Gynecology", "Midwife",
                true, HospitalWing.West);


        e.add(s);
        e.add(i);
        e.add(n);
        e.add(p);
        e.add(s1);
        e.add(n1);

        System.out.println(e.toString()); 
        System.out.println(Employee.numEmployees);
        System.out.println("-------------******--------------");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
        q = scan.nextLine();
        boolean j = false; 
        System.out.println("***************");

        for(Employee v: e){
            if(v.name.contains(q)){
                System.out.println(v.name);
                j = true; 
            }
        } 
        if(j == false){
            System.out.println("Name not found");
        }  
        System.out.println("----------------**************---------------");

        Scanner f = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the class of employees: ");
        w = f.nextLine();
        System.out.println("***************************"); 

        //PLEASE SHOW THE CODE HERE
    } 
}
```

Comment: Are you gonna try to code any of your problem? Coding up to the problem, but not coding the actual problem doesn't really help you much here.

Comment: You can try instance of operator

Comment: I would also like to see you make an effort to solve this problem.  I'm not interested in just flat out writing code for other people, especially when it the answer really isn't all that hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [The Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) to do this.
For example:

```
String className1 = e.getClass().getSimpleName();
String className2 = e.getClass().getName();
String className3 = e.getClass().getCanonicalName();
```

Chose one which suits you best considering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202997/what-is-the-difference-between-canonical-name-simple-name-and-class-name-in-jav) article.

Comment: I tried to upvote but i need to have a high reputation

Comment: Just click accept under the voting buton, please. Like in article: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers

Comment: Why you don't accept the answer, if it helped you? Don't get it.